# My ajax call always return an error, what can be done

Tags: json, jquery-mobile

Trying to understand json with examples. My example always return an error [Object object]. I tried to use data from stackoverflow with no luck to make this work. What is the best solution?

[Here is sample](http://jsfiddle.net/smatisen/JFV2H/20/).

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://meiepaev.ee/lazy/json.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 5000,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
         $.each(data, function(i,item){
            $ul.append('<li >' + item.nimi + '</li>');
        });
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('Error ' + data);
    }
```

Comment: If you look in the console, the actual error is: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://meiepaev.ee/lazy/json.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.  If you are calling into a different domain for your ajax, you need to research cross domain AJAX...

Comment: You're hitting Same Origin Policy problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: This link might help you http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2013/09/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-request.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matter is simple. AS of using PHP for generating json, adding

```
<?php
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

solve the problem. Thanks to everybody involved.